# How to run SQL Expression Query without any underlying database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, dummy-data, query-parser

I have a situation where the user enters some validation input in SQL format.
This SQL query is just using basic sql date functions but not using any databse column.
Sample query:

```
Select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) <= 10
THEN add_MONTHS(DATE_ADD(NOW(), (-1*DAYOFMONTH(NOW()))+1),-1)
ELSE DATE_ADD(NOW(), (-1*DAYOFMONTH(NOW()))+1) END)
```

I am able to run this when i have a connection object configured to some real database. But i do not find it worth to use a database and manage it just for this purpose. Is there a way where i can execute these type of queries or queries like select date() from dual etc in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, if you're going to make SQL database queries ... it's generally best to have a database to query against :)

Furthermore, if your purpose is to "test" your queries ... since many things are DB-specific - it's generally best to have an instance of the actual DB you wish to test against.

Having said that, there are many options for exercising SQL without an underlying database:

- You can use an on-line "fiddle" to test SQL queries, such as [SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)
- For unit tests, you'd use a mock framework.  For example, for Java/JUnit, I'd use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/).
- If I were testing Spring/Hibernate data access, I would use an in-memory, lightweight [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database.

There are really many, many alternatives.  It all just depends on your particular "use case"; what you're actually trying to accomplish.

PS:

I gave a number of Java examples.  Here's an article about mocking Microsoft/EF data calls:

https://entityframework.net/how-to-mock-data

Comment: my usecase is that, the end user inputs some validation to be performed before the actual logic to be executed. This needs to happen at runtime i.e.in Java code.
Since the user community is well versed with sql, he will be writing the validation in sql format. Because there is no actual DB data involved, i want to avoid having a physical database.
Looking for alternatives where i can skip having the physical database and still validate the sql expressions.

Comment: Frankly, my vote would be to use [H2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/h2_database/h2_database_introduction.htm).  It really sounds ideal for this use case.

Comment: Thanks. i used H2 DB for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

no, a sql query needs to run against a database engine.

For example select date() from dual is an oracle query; you can't run it against mssql or mysql.

Comment: He just took it as example that as Oracle supports this what about other servers. He doesn't mean to say that , he want to run `select date() from dual` in mssql or mysql.

Comment: 'You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced:' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html